# How to structure access to my private images in conversations using microservice and AWS?

Tags: javascript, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

(sorry for my english)

I'm pretty new in cloud architecture & microservices and
I struggle to design a process for my private images. Let me explain:
I have a mobile app (react native) in which I have private conversations between each user (basic chat app). In these conversations they can send images to each other. My question is how do I store these images (AWS S3) and make them private and only accessible for the 2 users of each conversation ? I have to create a powerful and scalable solution therefore impossible to store the images in a DB (I only map the urls). I was told about unique tokens allowing access to the image only once, does it really exist ?

Thank you in advance for your feedback!
Ps: I'm trying to use only S3, not all services from AWS

[image: Basic example of what I need]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my question:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html